# How to run a loop on a unique pairs of two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe

data:
[image]

on which i want to run a function on unique pairs of origin+destination and t_type.
Earlier I was only running  the function on t_type so I did this:

```
open_data = data[data['t_type']=="Open"].reset_index(drop=True)
all_data = data[data['t_type'] == "All"].reset_index(drop=True)
open = loader(open_data,open_trucks)    #open_trucks and all_trucks are
all = loader(all_data,all_trucks)       # from another dataframe
```

I retrieved the unique pairs from this:

```
data.groupby(['Origin','Destination']).size().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
Origin  Destination   0
Delhi   Doon          7
Delhi   Gurgaon       1
Delhi   Mumbai        8
.
.
.
```

How do i extract the data from the dataframe based on the O+D  ? I am sorry if i am repeating this but the segregation of data is twice here.. once on O+D and then on t_type.

I was thinking of this psuedo-code

```
for unique_pair in pairs:
    open_data = something(which I don't know how to extract)
    all_data = something(ditto)
    run the function and store the output
```

data:

```
          t_type Origin Destination
0        Open   Doon     Gurgaon
1        Open   Doon     Gurgaon
2        Open   Doon     Gurgaon
3   Container  Delhi      Mumbai
4   Container  Delhi      Mumbai
5        Open   Doon      Mumbai
6        Open  Delhi      Mumbai
7        Open  Delhi      Mumbai
8        Open  Delhi      Mumbai
9         All  Delhi        Doon
10        All  Delhi        Doon
11        All  Delhi        Doon
12        All  Delhi        Doon
13        All   Doon     Gurgaon
14        All   Doon      Mumbai
15       Open   Doon     Gurgaon
16  Container  Delhi     Gurgaon
17        All  Delhi      Mumbai
18        All  Delhi      Mumbai
19  Container  Delhi        Doon
20  Container  Delhi        Doon
21  Container  Delhi        Doon
22       Open  Delhi      Mumbai
23  Container   Doon       Delhi
24  Container   Doon       Delhi
25  Container   Doon       Delhi
26  Container   Doon       Delhi
27  Container   Doon     Gurgaon
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the output of `print(data[['t_type', 'origin', 'destination']])` in your answer, so we can reproduce a better answer? We cannot copy a picture. Furthermore, what kind of function would you like to run on these unique pairs?

Comment: So you want to select data in pairs of two categories? Why not use the groupby call to iterate over them and perform your computation? `for name, group in data.groupby(['Origin', 'Destination']):`. Or is there something I'm missing

Comment: Ya sure I will add the data and also the function which i want to run is name **loader**, it's in the code above.

Comment: If you just want to use the loader function you can use something like `data.groupby(['t_type', 'Origin', 'Destination']).apply(loader)`

Comment: @Erfan I have added the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
for i, df in data.groupby(['Origin','Destination']):
#if need processing by 3 columns 
#for i, df in data.groupby(['t_type', 'Origin', 'Destination']):
    print (df)
```

Or use custom function:

```
def func(df):
    print (df)
    #processing per groups

    return df

df1 = data.groupby(['Origin','Destination']).apply(func)
```

Comment: I have a function main which i want to call. Can I show that to you in chats ? maybe it'll help you help me better ?